# Closure confusion, share global variable between function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

```
    var data = null;

    socket.on('screen1', function (data) {

        data = data;
        console.log(data) // has something
    });

    $approve.click(function(){
        console.log(data) //null
        socket.emit('screen2', data);

    });
```

For some reason I can't put click event into socket.on because it's listening to the server. But I want its callback which is the `data`.I tried to do data = data and expect my click callback is able to get the data but it's still null.

Comment: `data = data` - think about it this way ... how do you know which data is which

Comment: Your `socket.on` handler is shadowing the outer `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local variable takes precedence over the global variable:

```
socket.on('screen1', function (data) { // <-- local variable "data"
    data = data;  // <-- both these "data" are the same variable!!
});
```

To access the global variable "data" rename the local variable to something else:

```
socket.on('screen1', function (d) {
    // Here I have no idea what your intention is. If I am
    // confused consider how the compiler is supposed to read
    // your mind.

    // You either wanted to do:
    d = data;

    // or data = d;

    // I cannot guess and neither can the compiler.
});
```

Comment: way more likely to be `data = d;` is the intention

Comment: It's almost definitely that OP wanted `data = d` since she is trying to access `data` later in the `click` handler.